# RXTX Library rxtxSerial.* file directory

Tags: java, operating-system, rxtx

I want to make a `Java` program and I use the `RXTX` library to Communications with an `Arduino`. 
Everything works fine on Windows, but I want to make program work on every operating System (or at least Linux). But i don't want to make multiple folder with the jar file and the right rxtxSerial.* File in it.

How do I make the program chose the right rxtxSerial.* File according to the operating System?
Can I Set the Directory for This file in the `RXTX` library?